# Return ID on MSAccess and has a datatype of AutoNumber(java)

Tags: java, database, ms-access-2007

I want to get the row of a record with a specific ID that has a type of 'AutoNumber.

I do it this way:

```
String sql = "select * from test where ID = '"+1+"'";
rs = st.executeQuery(sql);
```

It gives me this error ,

```
java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

How should i do it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your query 1 is of numeric data type.So don't put 1 into single quotes('1') 
**Because** Single quotes  converts char to varchar. And in your db it is numeric value.
So try after removing single quotes.

```
String sql = "select * from test where ID = "+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

If id is **integer** type then dont use single quotes.

```
String sql = "select * from test where ID = "+1;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove the single quotes.